# Aggregate GREATEST in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

My SQL is rusty -- I have a simple requirement to calculate the sum of the greater of two column values:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    column1 int NOT NULL, 
    column2 int NOT NULL
);

insert into Test (column1, column2) values (2,3)
insert into Test (column1, column2) values (6,3)
insert into Test (column1, column2) values (4,6)
insert into Test (column1, column2) values (9,1)
insert into Test (column1, column2) values (5,8)
```

In the absence of the GREATEST function in SQL Server, I can get the larger of the two columns with this:

```
select column1, column2, (select max(c) 
                            from (select column1 as c
                                   union all
                                  select column2) as cs) Greatest
  from test
```

And I was hoping that I could simply sum them thus:

```
select sum((select max(c) 
              from (select column1 as c
                     union all
                    select column2) as cs))
  from test
```

But no dice:

```
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Is this possible in T-SQL without resorting to a procedure/temp table?

UPDATE: Eran, thanks - I used this approach. My final expression is a little more complicated, however, and I'm wondering about performance in this case:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(column1 * column2) > ABS(column3 * column4)
         THEN column5 * ABS(column1 * column2) * column6
         ELSE column5 * ABS(column3 * column4) * column6 END)
```

Comment: Simplify like so: SUM(column5 * column6 * CASE WHEN ABS(column1 * column2) > ABS(column3 * column4) THEN ABS(column1 * column2) ELSE ABS(column3 * column4) END)

Comment: I know that @Eran answer is perfect for your current needs, but I suggest you take a look at my answer as it is a better replacement for `GREATEST`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column1 > column2 
                 THEN column1 
                 ELSE column2 END) 
 FROM test
```

Comment: This becomes very hard to read with more than 2 value columns, but for the OP it's probably the best.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... Its not the best performing option, but should work.

```
SELECT
  'LargerValue' = CASE 
                   WHEN SUM(c1) >= SUM(c2) THEN SUM(c1)
                   ELSE SUM(c2)
                  END
FROM Test
```

Comment: This gives me the answer of 26 for the test data above - should be 32

Comment: I don't want the greater of the two column sums, I want the sum of the greater of the two columns.

Comment: You want "a sum of the greater column values for each row"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    SUM(MaximumValue)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN column1 > column2
        THEN
            column1
        ELSE
            column2
        END AS MaximumValue
    FROM
        Test
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the more complicated case should be fine, so long as all of those columns are part of the same table. It's still looking up the same number of rows, so performance should be very similar to the simpler case (as SQL Server performance is usually IO bound).

Answer (score 0):

How to find max from single  row data

```
 -- eg (empid , data1,data2,data3  )
    select emplid , max(tmp.a)
    from
      (select emplid,date1 from table
      union 
      select emplid,date2 from table 
      union 
      select emplid,date3 from table
    ) tmp , table
    where tmp.emplid = table.emplid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(id) from (
    select (select max(c)
        from (select column1 as c
                union all
                select column2) as cs) id
  from test
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this is simply put :

```
;With Greatest_CTE As
(
  Select ( Select Max(ValueField) From ( Values (column1), (column2) ) ValueTable(ValueField) ) Greatest
    From Test
)
Select Sum(Greatest)
  From Greatest_CTE
```

It scales a lot better than the other answers with more than two value columns.